The undo and display history button did not work, i dont know what is wrong here


document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  const dimensionButton = document.getElementById('dimension-button');
  const dimensionElement = document.getElementById('dimension');
  const statusElement = document.getElementById('status');
  const restartButton = document.getElementById('restart-btn');
  const singlePlayerToggle = document.getElementById('single-player-toggle');
  const boardElement = document.getElementById('board');
  const historyBtn = document.getElementById('history-button');
  const undoButton = document.getElementById('undo-btn');

  let dimension = 10;

  dimensionButton.textContent = `${dimension}x${dimension}`;

  let singlePlayerMode = false;
  let squares = Array(dimension).fill(Array(dimension).fill(null));
  let xIsNext = true;
  let theWinner = null;
  let winningLine = [];
  const dimensions = [10, 12, 16, 20];
  let dimensionIndex = 0;

  dimensionButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
    stopTimer();
    dimensionIndex = (dimensionIndex + 1) % dimensions.length;
    dimension = dimensions[dimensionIndex];
    dimensionButton.textContent = `${dimension}x${dimension}`;
    restartGame();
  });
  //restartButton.addEventListener('click', restartGame);

  restartButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
    stopTimer(); // Stop the timer before restarting the game
    restartGame();
  });

  undoButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
    undoLastMove();
  });

  historyBtn.addEventListener('click', function() {
    console.log("History button clicked");
    stopTimer();
    displayLatestMatchMoves();
  });

  singlePlayerToggle.addEventListener('click', function() {
    stopTimer();
    toggleSinglePlayerMode();
    restartGame();
    if (singlePlayerMode && !xIsNext) {
      makeComputerMove();
    }
  });


  //UPDATE TIMING (10s each turn)
  const timingElement = document.querySelector('.timing');
  let timer;

  function startTimer() {
    resetTimer();
    let timeLeft = 10;
    timingElement.textContent = `Time left: ${timeLeft}s`;

    timer = setInterval(() => {
      if (theWinner) {
        clearInterval(timer);
        timingElement.textContent = '';
        return;
      }

      //if (!xIsNext) return;

      timeLeft--;
      timingElement.textContent = `Time left: ${timeLeft}s`;

      if (timeLeft === 0) {
        clearInterval(timer);
        if (singlePlayerMode && !xIsNext) {
          makeComputerMove();
        } else {
          xIsNext = !xIsNext;
          updateStatus();
        }
        //updateStatus();
        timingElement.textContent = '';
      }
    }, 1000);
  }

  function resetTimer() {
    clearInterval(timer);
    timingElement.textContent = '';
  }

  function stopTimer(forceStop = false) {
    if (forceStop) {
      clearInterval(timer); // Clear the interval to stop the timer
      timingElement.textContent = ''; // Clear the timing display
    } else {
      // Do nothing if forceStop is false
    }
  }


  function handleClick(row, col) {
    //update
    console.log("Clicked on row:", row, "column:", col);

    resetTimer();
    if (theWinner || squares[row][col]) return;

    const newSquares = squares.map((row) => [...row]);
    newSquares[row][col] = xIsNext ? 'X' : 'O';
    squares = newSquares;
    //squares = newSquares;
    xIsNext = !xIsNext;

    const winner = calculateWinner(newSquares, row, col);
    if (winner) {
      theWinner = winner;
      winningLine = findWinningLine(newSquares, row, col, winner);
    }

    //update match moves
    currentMatchMoves.push([row, col]);
    console.log("Current match moves:", currentMatchMoves);

    renderBoard();
    updateStatus();
    //update
    startTimer();

    if (singlePlayerMode && !theWinner && !xIsNext) {
      makeComputerMove();
    } else {
      startTimer();
    }

    if (theWinner) {
      recordMatchHistory();
    }
    recordMatchHistory();
    console.log("Move recorded:", row, col);
  }

  function calculateWinner(currentSquares, row, col) {
    const currentPlayer = currentSquares[row][col];

    // Check horizontally
    let count = 1;
    let leftCol = col - 1;
    while (leftCol >= 0 && currentSquares[row][leftCol] === currentPlayer) {
      count++;
      leftCol--;
    }
    let rightCol = col + 1;
    while (rightCol < dimension && currentSquares[row][rightCol] === currentPlayer) {
      count++;
      rightCol++;
    }
    if (count >= 5) {
      return currentPlayer;
    }

    // Check vertically
    count = 1;
    let topRow = row - 1;
    while (topRow >= 0 && currentSquares[topRow][col] === currentPlayer) {
      count++;
      topRow--;
    }
    let bottomRow = row + 1;
    while (bottomRow < dimension && currentSquares[bottomRow][col] === currentPlayer) {
      count++;
      bottomRow++;
    }
    if (count >= 5) {
      return currentPlayer;
    }

    // Check diagonally (top-left to bottom-right)
    count = 1;
    let topLeftRow = row - 1;
    let topLeftCol = col - 1;
    while (topLeftRow >= 0 && topLeftCol >= 0 && currentSquares[topLeftRow][topLeftCol] === currentPlayer) {
      count++;
      topLeftRow--;
      topLeftCol--;
    }
    let bottomRightRow = row + 1;
    let bottomRightCol = col + 1;
    while (bottomRightRow < dimension && bottomRightCol < dimension && currentSquares[bottomRightRow][bottomRightCol] === currentPlayer) {
      count++;
      bottomRightRow++;
      bottomRightCol++;
    }
    if (count >= 5) {
      return currentPlayer;
    }

    // Check diagonally (top-right to bottom-left)
    count = 1;
    let topRightRow = row - 1;
    let topRightCol = col + 1;
    while (topRightRow >= 0 && topRightCol < dimension && currentSquares[topRightRow][topRightCol] === currentPlayer) {
      count++;
      topRightRow--;
      topRightCol++;
    }
    let bottomLeftRow = row + 1;
    let bottomLeftCol = col - 1;
    while (bottomLeftRow < dimension && bottomLeftCol >= 0 && currentSquares[bottomLeftRow][bottomLeftCol] === currentPlayer) {
      count++;
      bottomLeftRow++;
      bottomLeftCol--;
    }
    if (count >= 5) {
      return currentPlayer;
    }

    return null;
  }

  function findWinningLine(currentSquares, row, col, winner) {
    const currentPlayer = currentSquares[row][col];
    const lines = [];

    // Check horizontally
    let leftCol = col - 1;
    while (leftCol >= 0 && currentSquares[row][leftCol] === currentPlayer) {
      lines.push([row, leftCol]);
      leftCol--;
    }
    lines.push([row, col]);
    let rightCol = col + 1;
    while (rightCol < dimension && currentSquares[row][rightCol] === currentPlayer) {
      lines.push([row, rightCol]);
      rightCol++;
    }
    if (lines.length >= 5) {
      return lines;
    }

    // Check vertically
    let topRow = row - 1;
    while (topRow >= 0 && currentSquares[topRow][col] === currentPlayer) {
      lines.push([topRow, col]);
      topRow--;
    }
    lines.push([row, col]);
    let bottomRow = row + 1;
    while (bottomRow < dimension && currentSquares[bottomRow][col] === currentPlayer) {
      lines.push([bottomRow, col]);
      bottomRow++;
    }
    if (lines.length >= 5) {
      return lines;
    }

    // Check diagonally (top-left to bottom-right)
    let topLeftRow = row - 1;
    let topLeftCol = col - 1;
    while (topLeftRow >= 0 && topLeftCol >= 0 && currentSquares[topLeftRow][topLeftCol] === currentPlayer) {
      lines.push([topLeftRow, topLeftCol]);
      topLeftRow--;
      topLeftCol--;
    }
    lines.push([row, col]);
    let bottomRightRow = row + 1;
    let bottomRightCol = col + 1;
    while (bottomRightRow < dimension && bottomRightCol < dimension && currentSquares[bottomRightRow][bottomRightCol] === currentPlayer) {
      lines.push([bottomRightRow, bottomRightCol]);
      bottomRightRow++;
      bottomRightCol++;
    }
    if (lines.length >= 5) {
      return lines;
    }

    // Check diagonally (top-right to bottom-left)
    let topRightRow = row - 1;
    let topRightCol = col + 1;
    while (topRightRow >= 0 && topRightCol < dimension && currentSquares[topRightRow][topRightCol] === currentPlayer) {
      lines.push([topRightRow, topRightCol]);
      topRightRow--;
      topRightCol++;
    }
    lines.push([row, col]);
    let bottomLeftRow = row + 1;
    let bottomLeftCol = col - 1;
    while (bottomLeftRow < dimension && bottomLeftCol >= 0 && currentSquares[bottomLeftRow][bottomLeftCol] === currentPlayer) {
      lines.push([bottomLeftRow, bottomLeftCol]);
      bottomLeftRow++;
      bottomLeftCol--;
    }
    if (lines.length >= 5) {
      return lines;
    }

    return [];
  }

  function renderBoard() {
    boardElement.innerHTML = '';
    for (let row = 0; row < dimension; row++) {
      const rowElement = document.createElement('div');
      rowElement.className = 'board-row';

      for (let col = 0; col < dimension; col++) {
        const value = squares[row][col];
        const isWinningSquare = winningLine.some(([winRow, winCol]) => winRow === row && winCol === col);

        const squareButton = document.createElement('button');
        squareButton.className = 'square';
        squareButton.style.backgroundColor = isWinningSquare ? 'yellow' : 'white';
        squareButton.style.color = value === 'X' ? 'blue' : 'red';
        squareButton.style.fontWeight = isWinningSquare ? 'bold' : 'normal';
        squareButton.textContent = value;
        squareButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
          if (!singlePlayerMode || (singlePlayerMode && xIsNext)) {
            handleClick(row, col);
          }
        });

        rowElement.appendChild(squareButton);
      }

      boardElement.appendChild(rowElement);
    }
  }

  function updateStatus() {
    if (theWinner) {
      statusElement.textContent = `Chiến thắng: ${theWinner}`;
    } else {
      statusElement.textContent = `Người chơi: ${xIsNext ? 'X' : 'O'}`;
    }
  }

  function restartGame() {
    squares = Array(dimension).fill(Array(dimension).fill(null));
    xIsNext = true;
    theWinner = null;
    winningLine = [];
    currentMatchMoves = [];

    renderBoard();
    updateStatus();
    //recordMatchHistory();

    if (singlePlayerMode && !xIsNext) {
      makeComputerMove();
    }
  }

  function makeComputerMove() {
    //update
    console.log("makeComputerMove called");
    console.log("singlePlayerMode:", singlePlayerMode);
    console.log("xIsNext:", xIsNext);
    console.log("theWinner:", theWinner);

    if (!singlePlayerMode || theWinner) {
      console.log("Exiting makeComputerMove early");
      return;
    }

    const availableMoves = [];
    const humanPlayer = xIsNext ? 'X' : 'O';
    const computerPlayer = xIsNext ? 'O' : 'X';

    squares.forEach((row, rowIndex) => {
      row.forEach((col, colIndex) => {
        if (!squares[rowIndex][colIndex]) {
          availableMoves.push([rowIndex, colIndex]);
        }
      });
    });

    if (availableMoves.length > 0) {
      // Check if the computer can win in the next move
      for (let i = 0; i < availableMoves.length; i++) {
        const [row, col] = availableMoves[i];
        const newSquares = squares.map((row) => [...row]);
        newSquares[row][col] = computerPlayer;

        if (calculateWinner(newSquares, row, col) === computerPlayer) {
          console.log("Computer winning move:", row, col);
          handleClick(row, col);
          return;
        }
      }

      // Check if the human player can win in the next move
      for (let i = 0; i < availableMoves.length; i++) {
        const [row, col] = availableMoves[i];
        const newSquares = squares.map((row) => [...row]);
        newSquares[row][col] = humanPlayer;

        if (calculateWinner(newSquares, row, col) === humanPlayer) {
          console.log("Human winning move:", row, col);
          handleClick(row, col);
          return;
        }
      }

      // Random move for normal difficulty
      const randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * availableMoves.length);
      const [row, col] = availableMoves[randomIndex];

      // Choose a winning move for hard difficulty
      if (availableMoves.length >= 3) {
        for (let i = 0; i < availableMoves.length; i++) {
          const [row, col] = availableMoves[i];
          const newSquares = squares.map((row) => [...row]);
          newSquares[row][col] = computerPlayer;

          if (isWinningMove(newSquares, computerPlayer)) {
            handleClick(row, col);
            return;
          }
        }
      }

      console.log("Computer random move:", row, col);
      handleClick(row, col);
    }
  }

  function isWinningMove(currentSquares, player) {
    for (let row = 0; row < dimension; row++) {
      for (let col = 0; col < dimension; col++) {
        if (!currentSquares[row][col]) {
          const newSquares = currentSquares.map((row) => [...row]);
          newSquares[row][col] = player;
          if (calculateWinner(newSquares, row, col) === player) {
            return true;
          }
        }
      }
    }
    return false;
  }

  function toggleSinglePlayerMode() {
    singlePlayerMode = !singlePlayerMode;
    if (singlePlayerMode) {
      singlePlayerToggle.innerHTML = '&#x1F4BB;';
    } else {
      singlePlayerToggle.innerHTML = '&#x1F477; ';
    }
  }
  renderBoard();
  updateStatus();

  //UNDO BUTTON
  function undoLastMove() {
    console.log("Undo button clicked");
    if (currentMatchMoves.length > 0) {
      // Remove the last move from the current match moves
      const [lastMoveRow, lastMoveCol] = currentMatchMoves.pop();
      // Reset the game state to the state before the last move
      squares[lastMoveRow][lastMoveCol] = null;
      xIsNext = !xIsNext;
      // Re-render the board and update the status
      renderBoard();
      updateStatus();
      stopTimer(true); // Stop the timer after undoing the move
    } else {
      alert("No moves to undo");
    }
  }

  //update history function
  let matchHistory = [];
  let currentMatchMoves = [];

  function recordMatchHistory() {
    console.log("Recording match history");
    console.log("Current match moves:", currentMatchMoves);
    if (currentMatchMoves.length > 0) {
      // Check if the current match moves are already in the match history
      const isDuplicate = matchHistory.some(historyMoves =>
        JSON.stringify(historyMoves) === JSON.stringify(currentMatchMoves)
      );

      // If the current match moves are not a duplicate, record them
      if (!isDuplicate) {
        matchHistory.push([...currentMatchMoves]); // Push a copy of currentMatchMoves
        console.log("Match history:", matchHistory);
      }

      // Reset current match moves after recording
      currentMatchMoves = [];
    }
  }

  function displayLatestMatchMoves() {
    console.log("Displaying latest match moves...");
    if (matchHistory.length > 0) {
      const latestMatchMoves = matchHistory[matchHistory.length - 1];
      console.log("Latest match moves:", latestMatchMoves);
      // Replay the latest match moves
      replayMatchMoves(latestMatchMoves);
    } else {
      alert("No match history available");
    }
  }

  function replayMatchMoves(moves) {
    // Reset the game state before replaying the moves
    squares = Array.from({
      length: dimension
    }, () => Array.from({
      length: dimension
    }, () => null));
    xIsNext = true;
    theWinner = null;
    winningLine = [];

    moves.forEach((move, index) => {
      const [row, col] = move;
      console.log("Replaying move:", row, col); // Log each move being replayed
      squares[row][col] = xIsNext ? 'X' : 'O'; // Update the squares array directly
      xIsNext = !xIsNext; // Toggle the player after each move

      // Update xIsNext based on the number of moves replayed
      if (index === moves.length - 1) {
        // If it's the last move, the next player depends on the total number of moves
        xIsNext = moves.length % 2 === 0;
      }
    });

    // Render the board after all moves are replayed
    renderBoard();
    // Update the status after replaying all moves
    updateStatus();
  }

});
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Cờ caro</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

</head>

<body>
  <div class="app">
    <div class="app-container">
      <h2 class="title">Cờ Caro</h2>

    </div>

    <div class="board">

      <div class="status" id="status"></div>
      <div class="list-button">
        <button class="button" id="restart-btn">
          <i class="bi bi-arrow-counterclockwise"></i>
        </button>
        <button class="button" id="single-player-toggle">&#x1F477</button>

        <button class="button" id="dimension-button">10x10</button>
      </div>


    </div>
    <div id="board" class="game"></div>
    <div class="timing"></div>
    <button class="history" id="history-button">History</button>
    <button id="undo-btn">Undo</button>
  </div>

  <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>



I want a display history button that display the latest match when you restart the game, and an undo button to undo 1 steps. But the display was not correct and the undo button always said "There is no moves to undo". I have watched through the console log, so I think there is something wrong with my logic in the function, but I don't know what is it.
Edit:

the history button did not display the latest match but generate a
random 'X' in the board from the console log, it seems that the
replay function only replay my final moves from the last match, i
have tried to fix it but it still only update the final moves.


Please [edit] and add your code in the question, not as an answer.

i have tried =((((((((( but somehow it always has error, i'm try to editing it rn

As it seems you are new here, so you might not know but this is not a forum to solve or fix your bugs. The questions needs to be concise and clear to the point and should be something that adds to the value of the stack. Please either remove the question or edit it so that it focus on to your exact problem you are facing. Since you are new and newbies tend to make this mistake, I am not giving a downvote unlike others but please fix the question

thanks for the reminder i will edit the question now

I have fix the question, do I need to fix it again?

IF you can please create a snippet and put the HTML in there also.  When you edit there is s <> button up top to create one. There is also a format for the code on the left of the snippet editor

I have put the HTML code into a snippet, thanks for the reminder :)

Note you can also cut the JavaScript out and put it in the snippet on the bottom left.  Snippets hold html, JavaScript and CSS as needed

You existing code works for undoButton.addEventListener('click', function () {         undoLastMove();     }); but it can simply be  undoButton.addEventListener('click', undoLastMove);
